# SQL - Filtering in many to many relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue coming up with the correct query for filtering in a many-to-many relationship, I think it's best understood through example:

I have four tables: `Post`, `PostTag`, `Tag`, and `User`, where `PostTag` is the join table between `Post`s and `Tag`s. The tags are `User`-specific - they belong to one user only and shouldn't be accessible by others.

I want to fetch the list of `Post`s with their `Tag`s, but fetch **only** the `Tag`s belonging to the logged in `User`.

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM post
    LEFT JOIN post_tag ON post.id = post_tag.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tag ON post_tag.tag_id = tag.id;
```

Above query returns all the Posts, but it also returns all of the Users tags, which is unwanted. My first instinct was to put it in a where query:

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM post
    LEFT JOIN post_tag ON post.id = post_tag.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tag ON post_tag.tag_id = tag.id
WHERE tag.user_id = :user_id;
```

But the above query basically turns the LEFT joins into INNER joins, and Posts without Tags do not get selected. So I tried putting it into JOIN condition:

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM post
    LEFT JOIN post_tag ON post.id = post_tag.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tag ON post_tag.tag_id = tag.id
        AND tag.user_id = :user_id;
```

The above does return all posts with only logged in user's tags, which is great, but I still have all the post_tags from other users which isn't ideal. So I found a way for excluding those with a simple WHERE:

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM post
    LEFT JOIN post_tag ON post.id = post_tag.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tag ON post_tag.tag_id = tag.id
        AND tag.user_id = :user_id
WHERE NOT (post_tag.id IS NOT NULL AND tag.id IS NULL)
```

The above query seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the right and the simplest solution.

Comment: Please **do not** spam tag RDBMS... please correct your tags to only include the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so we can understand your requirements.

Comment: Change all of your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Dai As shown by the last query, they also need posts that don't have any tags.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags... please add back the one of interest.

Comment: @MarcinJ Change _some_ of the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` then :)

Comment: @Dai that's the thing, it won't work just like that. If you change tag join to INNER, it effectively makes the post_tag INNER as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's time for one of the lesser known SQL constructs, I don't even remember what this type of join is called. Basically you do this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM post
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN post_tag
 INNER
  JOIN tag
    ON tag.id = post_tag.tag_id -- these join conditions apply to tag - post_tag
   AND tag.user_id = :user_id
    ON post_tag.post_id = post.id -- these apply to post_tag to post
```

The weird thing is the INNER JOIN comes directly after LEFT OUTER JOIN, and the ON clauses come after that in reversed order (basically first in first out). What that gets you is it tries to left join the post tags, but only the ones that inner join to tag where we filter by user_id. So the post_tag join is still left outer and will return posts without tags, but if it does have any tag, it needs to be one of the user's tags.

[Here's a working demo on db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e34fec8ea77ac780e8aa4c19a796b671)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way, avoiding the `post_tag` *junction-table* in the result set. (I presume you are only interested in the fields from `post` and `tag`, and these already contain the `post_id` and `tag_id` columns, though they are both named `id`):

---

```
SELECT *
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN tag t 
        ON t.user_id = :user_id
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM post_tag pt 
                WHERE pt.post_id = p.id
                AND  pt.tag_id = t.id
                )
        ;
```